# Removing last 4 characters with vba and replacing the new word/number in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I think there is probably a very easy solution to this question, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding it and I've only been using/learning VBA for a couple of days now.

I'm trying to use VBA to remove a space and the letters USD after a dollar figure. This occurs in only 3 specific cells in my worksheet and occurs on all subsequent worksheets in my workbook. Right now I'm not worried about looping through the other worksheets.

Below is the code I have found that works if I manually select the cell I want the code to work on, but I would like to tie this to a button so that the process happens without me having to choose the cell.

```
Sub RemoveUSD()

Dim Cell As Range, Str As String, StrLen1 As Integer, StrLen2 As Integer
    ' For each cell in your current selection
    For Each Cell In selection
        ' Set StrLen1 as the length of the current cell value
            StrLen1 = Len(Cell.Value)
            ' Set StrLen2 as the original length minus 3
            StrLen2 = StrLen1 - 3
                ' Set Str as the original cell value minus the last 3 characters
                Str = Left(Cell.Value, StrLen2)
        ' Update the adjacent cell with the shortened value
        Cell.Value = Str
     ' Check next cell in selection
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I would like to tie this to a button so that the process happens without me having to choose the cell....is a bit confusing, so do you want it to loop over all used cells in the worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just input the workbook name, worksheet name and range you want and this will do it for you. I put the `Trim` in just to take off any leading or trailing white space. To attached this to a button, add a button (Developer tab > Controls > Insert) and select the macro to attach to it.

```
Sub RemoveUSD()

Dim Cell As Range, rng as Range 
Dim Str As String
Dim StrLen1 As Integer, StrLen2 As Integer
With Workbooks("Daily MSR VaR Automation Attempt")
    With .Sheets("8-30 copy")
       Set rng = .Range("E2,N2,W2")
    End With
End With
    ' For each cell in your current selection
    For Each Cell In rng
        ' Set StrLen1 as the length of the current cell value
            StrLen1 = Len(Cell.Value)
            ' Set StrLen2 as the original length minus 3
            StrLen2 = StrLen1 - 3
                ' Set Str as the original cell value minus the last 3 characters
                Str = Trim(Left(Cell.Value, StrLen2))
        ' Update the adjacent cell with the shortened value
        Cell.Value = Str
     ' Check next cell in selection
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a run-time error that says "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. This is what I added as my rng.
    Set rng = Workbooks("Daily MSR VaR Automation Attempt").Sheets("8-30 copy").Range("E2", "N2", "W2")
Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: RAnge expect only two arguments so use this instead `Range("E2,N2,W2") `

Comment: See edited version. I also added the `With...End With` structure because it looks better to me :)

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly! Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly over a range plus check if

- the cell is at least four characters, and
- the last four characters are *" USD"*

For `A1:A30`

```
[a1:A30] = Application.Evaluate("=IF(LEN(A1:A30)>4,IF(RIGHT(A1:A30,4)="" USD"",LEFT(A1:A30,LEN(A1:A30)-4),A1:A30),A1:A30)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a version where you can define on execution which range should be chosen (based on the earlier solution posted):

```
Sub AdjustTrimRange()
Dim Cell As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "TrimRange"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

For Each Cell In WorkRng

            StrLen1 = Len(Cell.Value)
  ' Set amount to cut at the end of the string:
            StrLen2 = StrLen1 - 3

  ' cell value will be replaced by cell value minus number above,
  ' will trim for spaces at the beginning of the string:
                Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Cell.Value, Trim(Left(Cell.Value, StrLen2)))
    Next

End Sub
```